# echo not found in docker image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am creating a docker image in `alpine` and adding a `CMD` at the end, The image builds sucessfully, but when aI go to run the image:

```
CMD ["echo",  "some text"]  --- last line of image
```

**error**

```
/bin/sh: echo,: not found
```

Tried making it `/bin/echo`, but still get the same error. Do I need to start an interactive shell (`docker run -it image /bin/sh`). Thank you :).

```
/bin/sh: /bin/echo,: not found
```

Comment: If it isn't valid JSON, it isn't parsed as JSON

Comment: ...so when you have the extra quotes making it invalid JSON, the `,` stops being treated as JSON syntax and starts being treated as part of a literal command to be passed to a shell.

Comment: (Thus, I'd argue that this is a vote-to-close-as-typo candidate).

Comment: Sorry the extra `"` is a typo and has been removed... the command is formatted as in the answer. Thank you :).

Comment: ...so you accepted an answer (as fixing the issue) with the exact same code as what's now described in the question as causing your problem? I'm unclear on what someone is supposed to take away from this, then, if they have a similar error and are reading the question/answer pair.

Comment: After looking at what iI had in the `docker` file there was a extra space. Since I thought what I had written was the same as the answer I looked more carefully. I guess that is the take away message.. Im sorry and thank you :)

Comment: Ahh. Could you [edit] to add that extra space to the question, so it accurately represents the issue that the answer solves?

Comment: Added to post ... extra space after `echo`.

Comment: I had the error `echo,: not found` because I accidentally had written `\$` instead of `$` when trying to echo an env variable, e.g. `CMD ["echo", "\${PWD}"]` instead of the correct form `CMD ["echo", "${PWD}"]` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice how it's looking for `echo,` with a comma? Get rid of the extra quote that snuck in there.

```
CMD ["echo", "some text"]
```

Comment: this looks identical to the `CMD ["echo", "some text"]` in the question

Comment: @Patrick Michaelsen check characters between comma and quotes, he removed double blank space ;)

Comment: Astounding that makes a difference, but good to know!